# Razor view engine - How can I add Partial Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I was wondering what, if it is possible, is the best way to render a partial using the new razor view engine. I understand this is something that wasn't finished completely by the time

Right now I am using RenderPage to render the user control:

```
@RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/LocaleUserControl.cshtml",ViewData.Model)
```

The page calling RenderPage uses a layout (master) page with three sections defined: TitleContent, HeadContent and Maincontent. When I attempt to render my locale control from this page it appears that these sections are also required - they should only be required in the calling page and are present. I receive the following message, regardless of whether or not I include the sections in my partial view (obviously I dont want to include these sections but it seemed like an interesting debugging point...).

> The following sections have been
>   defined but have not been rendered on
>   the layout page
>   '~/Views/Shared/LocaleUserControl.cshtml':
>   TitleContent; HeadContent; MainContent

My partial view is as follows (adapted from the following [link](http://www.schnieds.com/2010/01/aspnet-mvc-locale-user-control.html)):

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<LocaleBaseModel>
@using System.Web.UI;

<p>
     @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.CountryName)
    <br />
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.CountryName,null, string.Empty, new { @class = "text", accesskey="u"})
</p>
<p>
     @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.StateProvince)
    <br />
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.StateProvince, null, string.Empty, new { @class = "text", accesskey="t" })
</p>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var countries = $("#CountryName");
        var statesprovinces = $("#StateProvince");
        countries.change(function () {
            statesprovinces.find('option').remove();
            var url = '@Url.Action("GetStatesProvinces", "Base")';
            $.getJSON(url, { countryId: countries.val() }, function (data) {
                $(data).each(function () {
                    $("<option value=" + this.ID + ">" + this.Name + "</option>").appendTo(statesprovinces);
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You partial looks much like an editor template so you could include it as such (assuming of course that your partial is placed in the `~/views/controllername/EditorTemplates` subfolder):

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SomePropertyOfTypeLocaleBaseModel)
```

Or if this is not the case simply:

```
@Html.Partial("nameOfPartial", Model)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback...

Html.EditorFor may be a good idea in this instance - but i'd be interested to see alternatives as this is not the case for more complex examples - i'll definitely be running into this again soon.



Html.Partial will not work as it must derive from ViewPage or ViewUserControl whereas the razor partial derives from WebViewPage...

Comment: Html.Partial works perfectly fine. Start a new ASP.NET MVC 3 project in Visual Studio using the Razor view engine, open the `_Layout.cshtml ` file in the `Shared` folder and checkout how the inclusion of `_LogOnPartial.cshtml` which derives from `WebViewPage` is done (using Html.Partial). So no, the partial doesn't need to derive from `ViewPage` or `ViewUserControl` at all for `Html.Partial` to work.

Comment: Hmmm, it looks like you are correct. It also looks like i've got some debugging to do. Thanks!

Comment: I used to use `Html.RenderPartial` with ASPX page, which returns void.  `Html.Partial` returns an `MvcHtmlString`.  So, if your partial contains lots of markup then you'll create a potentially very large string object only to GC it immediately.  Is there an approach that supports rendering directly to the output using Razor?

Comment: @Draw I think wrapping RenderPartial into a `@{...}` block should work. No idea if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to duplicate code, and like me you just want to show stats, in your view model, you could just pass in the models you want to get data from like so:

```
public class GameViewModel
{
    public virtual Ship Ship { get; set; }
    public virtual GamePlayer GamePlayer { get; set; }     
}
```

Then, in your controller just run your queries on the respective models, pass them to the view model and return it, example:

```
GameViewModel PlayerStats = new GameViewModel();

GamePlayer currentPlayer = (from c in db.GamePlayer [more queries]).FirstOrDefault();
```

[code to check if results]

```
//pass current player into custom view model
PlayerStats.GamePlayer = currentPlayer;
```

Like I said, you should only really do this if you want to display stats from the relevant tables, and there's no other part of the CRUD process happening, for security reasons other people have mentioned above.