# Create custom control in asp.net MVC3.0 with razor viewEngine

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to make a custom control in asp.net mvc3.0 with razor view engine just like we make in classic asp.net.
Please guide me how can I create a custom control or user control.

Comment: please go hrough following SO posts may it help you 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582866/custom-controls-with-asp-net-mvc-razor 2.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380945/razor-view-engine-how-can-i-add-partial-views

Comment: Thanks. but it would be easier for me to create if i could get step by step sample.......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a control, it's a helper, and you can read more here:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

Comment: No problem, it takes a little getting used to when you switch from web forms to MVC :-)